# I deleted my settings.json file in flutter project

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was following a tutorial online that said to reset my settings.json file.  I deleted everything inside and now my app hits a breakpoint in the main.dart file trying to runapp(myApp).  I have been unable to recover the original contents.

Would this even be the cause of the issue or would something else be doing this?  I am halfway able to run the app in profile mode but most of the content from the page is missing.

Comment: where was the settings.json located?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the configuration file of Visual Studio, it won't affect your app at runtime : your problem must be somewhere else.